# Carousell Controllers inside container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

im added a carousel to my website using boostrap framework, at first i inserted my carousel than added a container to give a paddings at the right and left, than i inserted after the carousel inner the carousel controllers, but for some reason the controllers is not getting the effect of the container.

Html:

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active"><img src="images/carousel-lifestyle.jpg" alt="Lifestyle Photo"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="images/carousel-mission.jpg" alt="Mission"></div>   
  <div class="item"><img src="images/carousel-vaccinations.jpg" alt="Vaccinations"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="images/carousel-fish.jpg" alt="Fish"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="images/carousel-exoticanimals.jpg" alt="Exotic Animals"></div> 
  </div>

   <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#featured" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#featured" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>

  </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put the controls inside `carousel-inner` see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sbgxwv8s/1/

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/1200/1200/" alt="Lifestyle Photo"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="images/carousel-mission.jpg" alt="Mission"></div>   
      <div class="item"><img src="images/carousel-vaccinations.jpg" alt="Vaccinations"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="images/carousel-fish.jpg" alt="Fish"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="images/carousel-exoticanimals.jpg" alt="Exotic Animals"></div>
 <!-- Controls --> 
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#featured" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#featured" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>

      </div>



  </div>
```